# What does the phrase "We're giving it everything we have" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "For me, I try to read everything I can, pray for wisdom, and make the choice I feel is best for myself and my family.”
>
> So, back to my first question. Can professional journalists make a difference? **We're giving it everything we have**.

Source: [USAToday](https://www.usatoday.com/story/opinion/2021/08/06/covid-vaccine-why-do-people-refuse-the-vaccine-here-are-reasons-and-responses/5491922001/)

I understand the phrase "We're giving it everything we have" as "we're making the great effort that we can make." Am I on the right track?

Comment: We're making the great**est** effort we can. :)

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. "We're giving it everything we have" is a usage of "giving it one's all" which is an idiom meaning "to put forth all one's effort". You can word it as "we are making the greatest effort that we can make", like you did (but note the superlative, which you missed).